# How'd i loop through every string.gmatch in a string then replacing the matches with a bytecoded version of that?

Tags: string, lua, match

How'd I change everything that it matches in the string without changing the non matches?

```
local a = "\" Hello World! I want to replace this with a bytecoded version of this!\" but not this!"

for i in string.gmatch(a, "\".*\"") do
    print(i)
end
```

For example I want `[["Hello World!" Don't Replace this!]]` to `[["\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33" Don't Replace this!]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local a = "\"Hello World!\" but not this!"

print(a:gsub('"[^"]*"', function(str)
  return str:gsub('[^"]', function(char)
    return "\\" .. char:byte()
  end)
end))
```

Comment: also for my current code usage right now, I also want it to ignore escape strings. How'd I do that?

Comment: I also need it to ignore other escape characters

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit tricky because it could involve:

- [Lua patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1)
- [`string.gsub` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub)
- Access to string's bytes with [`string.byte`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.byte)
- String concatenations with [`table.concat`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.concat)

First things first, if you need to implement `Lua` patterns, please know that there is a very handy `Lua` syntax which is very appropriate for dealing with *quoted strings*. With this syntax, instead of opening/closing a string with a double-quote, you do it with the characters `[[` and `]]`. The key difference is that between these markers, you don't have to escape the quoted strings anymore!

```
String = [["Hello World!" Don't Replace this!]]
```

Then, we need to build the proper `Lua` pattern, a possibility could be to match a double-quote (`"`) and then match all the characters which are **not** a double-quote (`"`), this gives us the following pattern:

```
[["([^"]+)"]]
  | ****  |
  |   \-> the expression to match
  |       |
 quote   quote
```

Then if we study the function [`string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub), we can learn that the function can call a `callback` when a pattern is matched, the matched string will be replaced by *the return value of the callback*.

```
function ConvertToByteString (MatchedString)
  local ByteStrings = {}
  local Len         = #MatchedString
  
  ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = [[\"]]
  
  for Index = 1, Len do
    local Byte = MatchedString:byte(Index)
    ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = string.format([[\%d]], Byte)
  end
  
  ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = [[\"]]
  
  return table.concat(ByteStrings)
end
```

In this `function`, we iterate through all the characters of the matched string. Then for each of the characters, we extract its byte value with the function [`string.byte`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.byte) and convert it to a string using the  [`string.format`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format) function. We put this string in a temporary array that we will concatenate at the end of the function.

The function to concatenate the sub-strings into a larger string is [`table.concat`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.concat). This is a very convenient function which could be used as follow:

```
> table.concat({ [[\10]], [[\11]], [[\12]] })
\10\11\12
```

The remaining thing we need to do is to test this outstanding function:

```
> String = [["Hello World!" Don't Replace this!]]
> NewString = String:gsub([["([^"]+)"]], ConvertToByteString)
> NewString
\"\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33\" Don't Replace this!
```

Edit: I got some remarks regarding code performances, I personally don't focus much on performances, I focus on getting the code correct & simple. In order to address the performance question, I wrote a micro-benchmark to compare the versions:

```
function SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer (String)
  local result = String:gsub('"[^"]*"', function(str)
                          return str:gsub('[^"]', function(char)
                                            return "\\" .. char:byte()
                          end)
  end)
  return result
end

function SOLUTION_Robert (String)
  local function ConvertToByteString (MatchedString)
    local ByteStrings = {}
    local Len         = #MatchedString
    
    ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = [[\"]]
    
    for Index = 1, Len do
      local Byte = MatchedString:byte(Index)
      ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = string.format([[\%d]], Byte)
    end
    
    ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = [[\"]]
    
    return table.concat(ByteStrings)
  end
  local Result = String:gsub([["([^"]+)"]], ConvertToByteString)
  return Result
end

function SOLUTION_Piglet (String)
  return String:gsub('%b""' , function (match)
                       local ret = ""
                       for _,v in ipairs{match:byte(1, -1)} do
                         ret = ret .. string.format("\\%d", v)
                       end
                       return ret
  end)
end

function SOLUTION_Renshaw (String)
  local function convert(str)
    local byte_str = ""
    for i = 1, #str do
      byte_str = byte_str .. "\\" .. tostring(string.byte(str, i))
    end
    return byte_str
  end
  local Result = string.gsub(String, "\"(.*)\"", function(matched_str)
                               return "\"" .. convert(matched_str) .. "\""
  end)
  return Result
end

String = "\"Hello World!\" Don't Replace this!"

print("INITIAL REQUIREMENT FROM OP ", [[\"\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33\" Don't Replace this!]])
print("TEST SOLUTION_Robert:       ", SOLUTION_Robert(String))
print("TEST SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer:", SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer(String))
print("TEST SOLUTION_Piglet:       ", SOLUTION_Piglet(String))
print("TEST SOLUTION_Renshaw:      ", SOLUTION_Renshaw(String))
```

The results show that only one answer fulfill 100% of OP's requirements. The other answers doesn't handle the first and ending double-quotes `"` properly.

```
INITIAL REQUIREMENT FROM OP     \"\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33\" Don't Replace this!
TEST SOLUTION_Robert:           \"\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33\" Don't Replace this!
TEST SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer:    "\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33" Don't Replace this!
TEST SOLUTION_Piglet:           \34\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33\34 Don't Replace this!  1
TEST SOLUTION_Renshaw:          "\72\101\108\108\111\32\87\111\114\108\100\33" Don't Replace this!
```

To finalize this post, one could dive a little deeper and check the code performances with a micro-benchmark which could be copy/paste directly in a `Lua` interpreter.

```
function SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer (String)
  local result = String:gsub('"[^"]*"', function(str)
                          return str:gsub('[^"]', function(char)
                                            return "\\" .. char:byte()
                          end)
  end)
  return result
end

function SOLUTION_Robert (String)
  local function ConvertToByteString (MatchedString)
    local ByteStrings = {}
    local Len         = #MatchedString
    
    ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = [[\"]]
    
    for Index = 1, Len do
      local Byte = MatchedString:byte(Index)
      ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = string.format([[\%d]], Byte)
    end
    
    ByteStrings[#ByteStrings+1] = [[\"]]
    
    return table.concat(ByteStrings)
  end
  local Result = String:gsub([["([^"]+)"]], ConvertToByteString)
  return Result
end

function SOLUTION_Piglet (String)
  return String:gsub('%b""' , function (match)
                       local ret = ""
                       for _,v in ipairs{match:byte(1, -1)} do
                         ret = ret .. string.format("\\%d", v)
                       end
                       return ret
  end)
end

function SOLUTION_Renshaw (String)
  local function convert(str)
    local byte_str = ""
    for i = 1, #str do
      byte_str = byte_str .. "\\" .. tostring(string.byte(str, i))
    end
    return byte_str
  end
  local Result = string.gsub(String, "\"(.*)\"", function(matched_str)
                               return "\"" .. convert(matched_str) .. "\""
  end)
  return Result
end

---
--- Micro-benchmark environment
---

COUNT = 600000

function TEST_Function (Name, Function, String, Count)
  local TimerStart = os.clock()
  for Index = 1, Count do
    Function(String)
  end
  local ElapsedSeconds = (os.clock() - TimerStart)
  print(string.format("[%25.25s] %f sec", Name, ElapsedSeconds))
end

String = "\"Hello World!\" Don't Replace this!"

TEST_Function("SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer", SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer, String, COUNT)
TEST_Function("SOLUTION_Robert",        SOLUTION_Robert,        String, COUNT)
TEST_Function("SOLUTION_Piglet",        SOLUTION_Piglet,        String, COUNT)
TEST_Function("SOLUTION_Renshaw",       SOLUTION_Renshaw,       String, COUNT)
```

The results shows that @DarkWiiPlayer's answer is the fastest one.

```
[   SOLUTION_DarkWiiPlayer] 6.363000 sec
[          SOLUTION_Robert] 9.605000 sec
[          SOLUTION_Piglet] 7.943000 sec
[         SOLUTION_Renshaw] 8.875000 sec
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked your solution against one that simply uses `gsub`? I can't imagine this one being performant unless using LuaJIT.

Comment: I think that performance is too often overrated. After a micro-benchmark I can say that your solution is the fastest of the 4 answers @DarkWiiPlayer.

Comment: I benchmarked it as well and mine is only faster on PUC Lua; on LuaJIT they're all about the same because the JIT just knows how to optimise them well enough

Answer (score 0):

you need `string.gsub`.

```lua
local a = "\"Hello World!\" Don't Replace this!"
local function convert(str)
  local byte_str = ""
  for i = 1, #str do
    byte_str = byte_str .. "\\" .. tostring(string.byte(str, i))
  end
  return byte_str
end
a = string.gsub(a, "\"(.*)\"", function(matched_str)
  return "\"" .. convert(matched_str) .. "\""
end)
print(a)
```

Comment: Your answer definitely works. But how'd I also detect escaped quotation marks?

Comment: also I noticed that detecting multiple strings in a string doesn't work. It only does 1 until the last string

Comment: you can refer https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1 from more information about match pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
local a = "\" Hello World! I want to replace this with a bytecoded version of this!\" but not this!"

print((a:gsub('%b""' , function (match)
  local ret = ""
  for _,v in ipairs{match:byte(1, -1)} do
    ret = ret .. string.format("\\%d", v)
  end
  return ret
end)))
```